# Oracle SQL group by and count with joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables,

the classes been taken by students

```
class_id student_id
-------------------
 1      |    2
 2      |    2
 3      |    1
```

the fees for each class

```
class_id class_tuition_fee class_item_fee
-----------------------------------------
1       |     100         |     45
2       |     20          |     null
3       |     30          |     100
```

the total number of items used for each class

```
class_id item_quant
-------------------
1       |  2
2       |  null
3       |  4
```

I wish to get the number of class, total fees of all classes, total number of items of all classes for each student.

For example, in this case

```
student_id num_class total_fee num_item
-----------------------------------------
1         |  1      |  130    |  4
2         |  2      |  165    |  2
3         |  0      |  0      |  0
```

Comment: Well, there is probably a student table, too. So, what is your question? It is nice telling us what you want to achieve, but what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please show your efforts, i.e. tell us the algorithm you have come up with or even show us the query you have, Then explain your issue with that.

Comment: You have tagged a database tool (Oracle SQL Developer). It doesn't look like you want information on this tool, but rather seek help on a SQL query, and your DBMS should be Oracle then. You haven't asked a question, but I have taken the liberty of changing the tags.

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2778710)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, students table is missing - without it, there's no way to fetch the 3rd row in target table. If we include it, that's more or less bunch of outer joins (as it is unclear what rows can, and what can't be missing) with some aggregations.

Something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  stu (student_id) as
  3    (select 1 from dual union all
  4     select 2 from dual union all
  5     select 3 from dual
  6    ),
  7  cbs (class_id, student_id) as
  8    (select 1, 2 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 2 from dual union all
 10     select 3, 1 from dual
 11    ),
 12  fec (class_id, class_tuition_fee, class_item_fee) as
 13    (select 1, 100, 45   from dual union all
 14     select 2,  20, null from dual union all
 15     select 3,  30, 100  from dual
 16    ),
 17  iec (class_id, item_quant) as
 18    (select 1, 2    from dual union all
 19     select 2, null from dual union all
 20     select 3, 4    from dual
 21    )
```

Query:

```
 22  select
 23    s.student_id,
 24    count(c.class_id) num_class,
 25    sum(nvl(f.class_tuition_fee, 0) + nvl(class_item_fee, 0)) total_fee,
 26    nvl(sum(i.item_quant), 0) as num_item
 27  from stu s left join cbs c on c.student_id = s.student_id
 28             left join fec f on f.class_id = c.class_id
 29             left join iec i on i.class_id = c.class_id
 30  group by s.student_id
 31  order by s.student_id;

STUDENT_ID  NUM_CLASS  TOTAL_FEE   NUM_ITEM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        130          4
         2          2        165          2
         3          0          0          0

SQL>
```